# Migrating App Account

Tags: data-transfer, accounts

I'm migrating content from one android tablet to another. The older device is running 4.4.2 and the newer 6.0.1.

I've successfully transferred almost all app data and game data from the old device, aside from a game called "Casino X".

I've backed up the game data using Helium, then restored on the new device but it's just ignored. I noticed that there's an "account" for this game under `Settings \ Accounts` called `Casino X \ api-casino.itemboxapps.com`.

How can I transfer the `Account` to the new device?

Answer (score 0):

You should try copying the files onto a online drive (such as google drive) and then downloading the files onto the new device.
Edit: Apologies, I read it wrong.
You should try reinstalling/launching the game to see if it reinstalls the profile.
Worst case scenario, root both devices.

Comment: How do I copy the files when they're not accessible using Android File Transfer or sync'able on the device?